# Как вывести два количества записей по условию одним SELECT?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Вот условие:

> Составить запрос с использованием таблицы8, который
> выводит одним предложением  `select`  два  числа.
> Первое  число  – количество  жителей  с  фамилией  Волков  или  Волкова.
> Второе  число  – количество жителей с фамилией Зайцев или Зайцева.

Единственное, что в нём откровенно напрягает, так это то, что нельзя использовать больше одного `select` и, следовательно, подзапросы.

Я, конечно, пытался разрешить это посредством алиасов, но это не помогло:

```sql
SELECT FIO VOLKOVI, FIO ZAICEVI FROM ELEKTROSTAL WHERE VOLKOVI LIKE 'Волков%'
```

---

П.С. Я знаю, как вывести количество, и знаю, что забыл про условие для второго столбца: всё это я напишу сам, но только после того, как разберусь с селектами и псевдонимами.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вы наверное не совсем разобрались, как работает данный сайт. Если у вас появилось чуство, что в данной теме вас обидели, поступили не справедливо, то вы можете [задать вопрос на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Начинать "войну минусов" в этом случае, явно не стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильное решение такое:

```
select 
    count (case when lastname in ('Волков','Волкова') then 1 end) "Волковы", 
    count (case when lastname in ('Зайцев','Зайцева') then 1 end) "Зайцевы" 
from t8
where lastname in ('Волков','Волкова','Зайцев','Зайцева')
```

Тестовые данные и результат запроса выше:

```
create table t8 (lastname) as
    select trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('
        "Волков", "Волкова", "Зайцев","Зайцева",
        "Сидоров","Сидорова","Петров","Петрова"');

   Волковы    Зайцевы
---------- ----------
         2          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну это просто. Расписывать не стану. Покажу, как считать количество.

```
SELECT 
     sum(case when family = 'волковы' then 1 else 0 end ) countWolfs, 
     sum(case when family = 'зайцевы' then 1 else 0 end ) countRabbits 
FROM table8
```

Можно и через `count`, но идея останется прежней. Считаем только тех, кто нужен.