# Почему не работает цикл (не обходится второй узел)?

Tags: c#, xml, closedxml

Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка!
Вот фрагмент XML:

```
<MessageInfo MessageType="StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy">
<StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy>
  <CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship>
    <MonetaryObligations>
      <MonetaryObligation>
        <CreditorName>ао тинькофф банк</CreditorName>
        <CreditorRegion>г. Москва</CreditorRegion>
        <CreditorLocation>123060 г. москва 1-й волоколамский проезд 10</CreditorLocation>
        <Content>кредитный договор</Content>
        <Basis>кредитный договор №0219164910 от 08.09.2016</Basis>
        <TotalSum>220449.4</TotalSum>
        <DebtSum>220449.4</DebtSum>
        <PenaltySum xsi:nil="true" />
      </MonetaryObligation>
      <MonetaryObligation>
        <CreditorName>поа сбербанк</CreditorName>
        <CreditorRegion>Рязанская область</CreditorRegion>
        <CreditorLocation>рязань ул. пожалостина, 19</CreditorLocation>
        <Content>кредитный договор</Content>
        <Basis>кредитный договор</Basis>
        <TotalSum>46590.94</TotalSum>
        <DebtSum>46590.94</DebtSum>
        <PenaltySum xsi:nil="true" />
      </MonetaryObligation>
    </MonetaryObligations>
    <ObligatoryPayments />
  </CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship>
  <IsIndividualEntrepreneur>false</IsIndividualEntrepreneur>
  <CreditorsFromEntrepreneurship>
    <MonetaryObligations />
    <ObligatoryPayments />
  </CreditorsFromEntrepreneurship>
  <Banks />
  <TaxOffices />
</StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy>
```

Вот код:

```
XmlNode MonetaryObligation = messageRoot.SelectSingleNode("//MessageInfo/StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy/CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship/MonetaryObligations/MonetaryObligation");
                     
foreach (XmlNode childnode in MonetaryObligation.ChildNodes) {
    if (childnode.Name == "CreditorName") Console.WriteLine($"Банк:  {childnode.InnerText}");
    if (childnode.Name == "TotalSum")     Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {childnode.InnerText}");
}

Console.WriteLine(" ------end-----");
```

Вывод:

```
Банк:  ао тинькофф банк
Сумма: 220449.4
------end-----
```

Почему выводится информация только по первому банку?

Comment: думаю что на этот вопрос ответит дебаггер с брейкпоинтами. Тем более при таком оформлении вопроса)

Comment: пробовал я дебаггер, просто цикл выполнился один раз и все.

Comment: мало пробовать дебаггер, нужно еще и значения просмотреть в переменных что бы понять почему он выполнился только 1 раз и все) Иначе в чем смысл дебага?) А если бы ты это сделал, то ответ сам бы всплыл в твоей голове

Comment: Странно вы как то делаете, берете один объект, а потом ищите в нем `ChildNodes`, может тогда уж лучше сразу брать то, что надо? `SelectSingleNode` -> `SelectNodes` (если он там есть (должен)) и `MonetaryObligation.ChildNodes` меняете просто на `MonetaryObligation`.

Comment: Можете код написать? Не понимаю

Comment: @qqqq1961 Надо запомнить вас чтоб не помогать. Нето помогаешь решить задачу. А тут ещё чайки налетают и умничают.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вы серьезно? Кинули обиду, оскорбили меня и все ради чего? Я кинул вон комментарием выше жирную подсказку того, как надо, могли ведь взять и написать грамотный ответ, объяснить автору что он не так делает, но нет, вы пофиксили его костыль, добавив ряд своих и что, хотите, чтоб вас за это погладили по голове? Ну давайте я пройдусь по вашим ответам и поставлю лайки им, раз вы такой алчный человек, который ради репутации тут сидит и продает костыли, только не забывайте, что на SO мы помогает не только авторам вопросов, но и будущим читателям, а какая им будет польза от вашего ответа?

Comment: Евгений я же не говорю о том что я алчный или ваш ответ неверный. Я оттом что ответ был полезный а спустя время нет. Реч ведь не о баллах или плюшках там каким то. А о подходе.

Comment: Может и сгореча второй день подряд авторы снимают галочку после того как получен ответ. Ладно бы неверный или ошибочный я здраво отношусь к критике не болею всякими там фобиями. Обидно помочь человеку которому никто не помог по сути только в комментариях расписался. Затем снять галочку потому что пришел ответ более грамотно оформленный. Ведь под стрелками стоит ответ полезный а не правильный или прочий. Полезный не для сообщества а для автора вопроса. Какая польза автору после того как он решил задачу другим путем

Comment: @AzizUmarov Так, давайте по порядку, вот сейчас два ответа, какой, по-вашему, больше несет пользы для SO и автора? Ваш, где вы не пойми зачем пишете цикл в цикле, без каких-либо объяснений, или мой, где я автору сказал, как надо решить задачу, решил ее, объяснил все его "косяки" и сказал, как лучше поступить правильней? Я лично у вас вижу лишь код и костыли, все, по этому, пользы от него я не увидел, а если бы увидел, то не писал бы свой ответ. Так в "более грамотном оформление" тут речь или больше в полезности?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  На счёт костылей. У меня принцип немного другой. Человек заблудился в лесу я его веду, а не телепортирую к бабушке с пирожками. Можете посмотреть по моим ответам.

Comment: @AzizUmarov `Какая польза автору после того как он решил задачу другим путем` - наверно в том, что он не знает изначально как надо и то, что мы видим, это его попытки решения, попытки новичка и он хочешь получить помощь, которая подскажет ему как более грамотно поступить в этом случае?

Comment: @AzizUmarov `Можете посмотреть по моим ответам` - я помню ваш ответ на мой вопрос, где вы просто сказали "Ну парниш, ну они ведь разные, чего ты хотел то?", где я вас еще затчкой назвал, ибо вы просто "заткнули" мой вопрос, сделав его проходным для многих участников, ибо на SO если есть ответ, то значит "на нем не заработать" и туда не заходят. Ну нельзя так, думайте не только о себе и авторе, думайте и об окружающих, ответы должны быть полезны всем, а не только неумелому автору, который даже и подумать не мог, что у него "костыль".

Comment: @AzizUmarov Так что, может с вас не просто так снимают "галки" и стоит задуматься о том, а правильно вы это все отвечаете? Подумайте на досуге. Всего наилучшего как говориться.

Comment: И вы же до сих пор считаете что я не прав. А заклевали меня. Хотя я был прав и вы это знаете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116826/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-evgeniyz).

Comment: @AzizUmarov, извиняюсь, думал, что можно два правильных ответа пометить. Не читал никогда Правила сайта. Не заметил, что с Вас галочка слетела, когда другой ответ пометил. Спасибо еще раз за быстрое решение!

Comment: Снимите галку пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
XmlNode MonetaryObligations = messageRoot.SelectSingleNode("//MessageInfo/StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy/CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship/MonetaryObligations");
                     
foreach (XmlNode MonetaryObligation in MonetaryObligations.ChildNodes) {
  foreach (XmlNode childnode in MonetaryObligation.ChildNodes) {
    if (childnode.Name == "CreditorName") Console.WriteLine($"Банк:  {childnode.InnerText}");
    if (childnode.Name == "TotalSum")     Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {childnode.InnerText}");
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(" ------end-----");
```

Во избежание второго цикла попробуйте его переписать так

```
Console.WriteLine($"Банк:  {MonetaryObligation["CreditorName"].InnerText}");
 
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {MonetaryObligation["TotalSum"].InnerText}");
```

Comment: Да, так заработало, спасибо! Но почему два цикла?

Comment: Первый чтоб по облигациям второй собственно и не нужен можно сразу взять конкретные значения. В данном случае мне проще было взять ваш код и дописать

Comment: Ну так я и пытался взять конкретные значения без второго цикла. Как же их взять то?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Перепишите вместо внутреннего цикла

Comment: Условие конечно если такая нода есть

Comment: Да, так гораздо лучше, Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: XmlNode MonetaryObligations = messageRoot.SelectSingleNode("//MessageInfo/StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy/CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship/MonetaryObligations");
                            if (null != MonetaryObligations)
                            { 
                                foreach (XmlNode monetaryObligation in MonetaryObligations)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Банк:  {monetaryObligation["CreditorName"].InnerText}");
                                }
                            }

Comment: Ну и innerText у null тоже нет, может исключение вбросить

Answer (score 4):

У вас изначально неверная логика работы, ибо вы ищете первый попавшийся `MonetaryObligation`, а потом "пляшете" от него, взят все дочерние элементы, зачем эти лишние действия, если можно сразу взять то, что вы хотите. Давайте так и поступим:

- Меняем `.SelectSingleNode()` на `.SelectNodes()`, ибо он берет все найденные элементы, соответствующие данному `XPath`. Получаем такое:

  ```
  var MonetaryObligation = messageRoot.SelectNodes("//MessageInfo/StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy/CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship/MonetaryObligations/MonetaryObligation");
  ```
- Далее убираем `.ChildNodes` у `foreach`, ибо предыдущий шаг нам уже выдал коллекцию нужных нам объектов.

  ```
  foreach (XmlNode childnode in MonetaryObligation)
  ```
- Теперь вывод, меняем его на примерно такой вид:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine($"Банк: {childnode["CreditorName"]?.InnerText}");
  Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {childnode["TotalSum"]?.InnerText}");
  ```

  Думаю, вы уже поняли, что у нас на руках сейчас нода `<MonetaryObligation>`, из нее то мы и получаем необходимые значения, просто, по ключу, а знак `?`(вопроса) не даст выполниться правой части кода, если такого значения нету и выведет просто пустоту.

Собственно весь код будет таким:

```
var MonetaryObligation = messageRoot.SelectNodes("//MessageInfo/StartOfExtrajudicialBankruptcy/CreditorsNonFromEntrepreneurship/MonetaryObligations/MonetaryObligation");

foreach (XmlNode childnode in MonetaryObligation)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Банк: {childnode["CreditorName"]?.InnerText}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {childnode["TotalSum"]?.InnerText}");
}

Console.WriteLine(" ------end-----");
```

---

Немного полезного.

1. Если вы в `XPath` пишете `//`, то это означает "искать по всему документу и всем нодам", да, думаю вы уже догадались, что не обязательно писать весь путь и весь `XPath` сводится к простому `"//MonetaryObligation"`.
2. В C# есть как по мне, более продвинутая и удобная версия парсера XML, зовется `XDocument` (из `System.Xml.Linq`) и там вам вообще `XPath` не понадобиться, ибо если переписать код выше на него, то выйдет нечто такое:

   ```
   foreach (var obligation in xDoc.Descendants("MonetaryObligation"))
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Банк: {obligation.Element("CreditorName")?.Value}");
       Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {obligation.Element("TotalSum")?.Value}");
   }
   ```

   Как видите, ни единой строчки `XPath`, а лишь простые методы `.Element()`, `.Elements()`, `.Descendants()`, да и значение сразу `.Value`. Это конечно дело вкусов и на этом примере особо не показать что с ним можно, но как вариант, знайте.

   Ну а вообще, я вам настоятельно рекомендую при работе с подобными объектами, в первую очередь, искать способы их [десериализации/сериализации](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php), ибо когда у вас данные храниться в классе, это не только удобно, но и сберегает кучу нерв и сил в дальнейшем, ибо если вдруг в вашем XML измениться хоть одно название, то вы будете искать во всем проекте где вы его используете в виде простой строки, а имея класс, вам надо лишь поменять название нужного свойство и во всех других местах вы сразу получите ошибку о несущесвующем имени.

Comment: Cпасибо, сейчас разберу эти советы!

Comment: От меня -1 +10 вам

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да чего вы слились то сразу, дайте мне понять ваш поступок, вашу логику...

Comment: Логика как я сказал не баллы а помощь

Comment: @AzizUmarov Это не объясняет тот факт, что вы "бомбанули" из за снятой галки, раз есть ответ намного полезный.

Comment: Ьомбанул я сказал почему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211177/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-select/1211185#1211185

Comment: @AzizUmarov Ну так принятый ответ вроде дает больше полезной информации, чем ваш, не? Вы оба получили +20 баллов, за галку тот ответ получил дополнительно ничтожных +5, вы нечего не потеряли, все хорошо, все здорово, чего сразу бомбить то? Радоваться надо, что один из ответов на SO получить чуть лучшее решение, а не негатив кидать..

Comment: Там тоже ответ с костылями но появилось вдруг с развернутым ответом и учит меня как правильно читать. Читать я умею вы наверное поняли, а принижать правильным ответом обидно

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете что ложка дорога к обеду. И ответ написан с телефона дабы не расписывать а помочь человеку

Comment: Человек не понимал дал наводку. А тут на тебе здрасьте. Я оказывается пишу неверно и читать не умею

Comment: @AzizUmarov Я это понимаю, но и вы должны понимать, что чем полезней ответ на SO, тем лучше и грех кидать обидку на то, что с вашего простенького ответа, написанного с телефона, вдруг сняли галку из-за того, что появилось что-то более полезней. Сколько с меня этих галок за все 4 года, что я здесь был поснимали, вы не представляете, но ничего, смотрю на ответы и вижу там много полезного, то, что я упустил, ставлю лайк и радуюсь за человека, ну не злиться ведь мне на него, что он написал что-то лучше?

Comment: Я конечно не националист. Но насмехаться над человеком не носителю языка в том что у него плохо с русским думаю не в его пользу

Comment: Поймите писать ответ другое принижать труд другого это не есть хорошо это моя личная позиция

Comment: Хочешь опубликовать ответ. Да пожалуйста только вот авторитетом не дави (я это не вам). Мне ровно сколько у кого репы. Важен результат. А по поводу верности или нет ответа все это чушь. Это был конкретный случай как и тут. Я уверен что найдется ответ на подобный вопрос на который есть вразумительный ответ. Я давно понял что проблемы у новичков в принципе одинаковые.

Comment: Конкретно одна проблема. Не желание думать иначе и находить пути решения самому

Comment: @AzizUmarov Но не вы один на это сайте, единоличником быть тоже не есть хорошо. Наша цель, как сообщества SO - собрать хорошую, добротную базу ответов на хорошие вопросы, иногда, решений поставленного вопроса может быть несколько, а иногда, то решение, что уже дали не совсем верное. В конкретном случае я считаю ваше решение "костылем", которое можно и даже нужно переписать, написать иначе, что я и продемонстрировал в своем ответе. Не было бы моего ответа, автор и дальше использовал костыли, он бы не знал как ему правильно поступить, ибо вы ему лишь дали рыбу, а я дал удочку и научил как ловить

Comment: @AzizUmarov `Конкретно одна проблема. Не желание думать иначе и находить пути решения самому` - по этой причине я очень редко даю ответы, ибо большинству вопросов на SO попросту не место, ибо это либо домашка, либо нежелание думать) По этой причине я пишу лишь комментарии, в надежде, что вопрос удалит система.

Comment: Болото и только. Вот и помогаю в конкретных случаях конкретным советом. Не всегда укладываюсь в комментариях и пишу ответ покороче

Comment: @AzizUmarov Не берите вы все близко к сердцу, живите проще. А ответы, давайте только тогда, когда есть на это желание, время и силы, все же, чем информативней, тем лучше, просто кусок кода чаще вызывает больше вопросов, чем дает ответов.

Comment: Вот вам 2 примера. Которые помогли. А ответы вы у меня в основном код и немного текста. Объяснять смысл ,читать не будут ибо если уметь читать и находить то суда за чтением литературы не будут. А человек он дурак на чужих ошибках не учится, ибо не было бы столько войн

Comment: @AzizUmarov Не, я не спорю, что порой этого достаточно, но большинство новичков на SO это все же новички и в программирование, а порой и вовсе дети, которые толком не умеют даже следовать инструкции, и думаете им поможет подобный подход? Нет конечно. Также и будущие читатели аналогично, они не профессионалы, раз такое ищут, а значит, надо опуститься на их уровень и разжевать все подробней, тогда, хоть какая-то польза и будет от ответа. Тут стоит все же оценивать уровень вопроса и автора данного вопроса.

Comment: Да откуда от козла молока? Я сам порой удивляюсь почему я до сих пор тут. Болото засосало или просто спортивный интерес не понятно какие призы подарки. Может изучаю проблемы или набираю абы какой опыт, не знаю. Помогаю и всё. Будущее я в него не верю его нет есть сейчас. Завтра .. его знает наступит или нет увидим завтра

Comment: Из этих тупых или нет непонятно соображений я помогаю сейчас советом или костылем кому как угодно я в гости никому не напрашиваюсь. Изменять ответ свой тоже не имею привычки, может и зря а может и бред. Одним словом философия. Вопросов много, а смысла нет

Comment: На счёт опускания на их уровень. У кого там в статусе было. Не спорь с дураком, заташит на свой уровень и задавит опытом